# Periodic wave that oscillates between two discrete values

Tags: graphing-functions

I feel like I have seen one before, maybe in a simulation in Desmos, but is there a wave that looks like the following picture that changes between two values. And if so, what is it called?

[Picutre of graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcNN9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is called [square wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_wave).
If $w(t)$ is the square wave
$$
w(t) = \mathrm{sign}\left(\sin\left(\frac tT\right)\right)
$$
and you want a wave that oscillates between values $a$ and $b$, then you can consider
$$
\frac{a+b}2 + \frac{b-a}2 w(t) .
$$

Of course to change the period you change $T$ and to shift in time you use $w(t-t_0)$.